# Send and Receive remote events in iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, message

I am working on a iOS app for food delivery service. And I want to send events from shopkeeper end to customer end and vice-versa.

My app is an iOS app. It is running on iPad 3 at shop end and a user can use iPhone for placing the order. So what is the appropriate method for communication and listening events? For example:

Customer performs a food request. Shopkeeper should be notified immediately.
When shopkeeper accepts it, an acknowledgment should be sent customer side.

Thanks

Comment: You can try the MultipeerConnectivity framework. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

Comment: Tried push notification?

Comment: Example tutorial for [`MultipeerConnectivity`](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/) - `Swift`.

Comment: Yes I have tried Push notification with **Data Message** type. It worked but I am not sure Push Notification is for this purpose or not. In addition to this I have also tried Firebase Live DB observers as events!!

Comment: Will give MultipeerConnectivity framework a try. Thanks